# Arranging numbers on a cycle such that each pair differ by one prime factor?

Tags: number-theory

Is it possible to place 2019 natural numbers along a circumference so that, for any two of these numbers, the proportion of the largest to the least is a prime number?

Ok, what I am clear about this problem is that for the ratio to be a number first, it means that given any two numbers, its mcd can not be 1, because in this way we make sure that at least the proportion is a natural number ... However, I am not very clear on how to interpret the part in which it says that they are located along a circumference, that is, How different is it if we place it on a straight?

Comment: This looks like a competition problem. Is it a competition problem? Where is it from?

Comment: Let's see if I understood the question, so let's start with just 3 numbers $a<b<c$, so if I pick up any 2 of them, their proportion should be prime. So let $\frac{c}{a}=m$, $\frac{c}{b}=n$, $\frac{b}{a}=k$, where $k,m,n$ are prime, then $k=\frac{m}{n}$ which tells us that it is impossible to place 3 natural numbers using above requirements

Comment: maybe you have to check the question again, it is stated a little bit strangely

Comment: Are we comparing *any* pair of numbers ? Or only pairs that are neighbours reading round the circle ? The questions as stated doesn't say we only compare neighbours, but without this restriction the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, it is a question of competence (mathematical olimpadas), because it was written like that, I said 2019 natural numbers, they do not clarify much of what order or something, so my question, I still do not understand why necessarily in a circle

Comment: I have the question in Spanish, however I think I translated it well

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote the numbers by $x_0,\ldots,x_{m-1}$, where in your case $m = 2019$. Let $P(x)$ denote the number of prime factors of $x$. Your condition implies that $P(x_i) = P(x_{i+1}) \pm 1$, and in particular $P(x_i) \equiv P(x_{i+1}) + 1 \pmod{2}$, where the indices are modulo $m$. Summing this over all $i$, we get the contradictory $0 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, since $m$ is odd.

In contrast, if $m$ is even, then there is always a solution. I will illustrate this with $m = 6$:
$$
1,2,4,8,4,2.
$$
The general solution is similar.

Comment: You guys are sure in a very supportive mood... no wonder I stopped participating.

Comment: or in general, we can get the ratio between the largest and the smallest to be a prime number if and only if the number of natural numbers located in the circumference is even

Comment: It's like that, right?

Comment: Right, it depends only on the parity.

Comment: Why mod 2? because the indices are two?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: That’s what the proof gives.

Comment: :oooooo, I understand, I understand hahaha thank you very much